# Python 3.x: Trying to loop through each item in a list and then calculate whether items are decreasing or increasing for certaiintervals

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

```
lista= []                     # Creates a blank/empty list
inp = 0                       # Input is not negative yet
while inp >= 0:               # While loop
    inp = int(input("Put numbers. Enter negative number to stop") 
    if inp >= 0:
        lista.append(inp)  # Adds numbers inputted to list
    else:
        break                 # Break if number is less than 0 (negative)
```

So, the above code is to create a list with numbers. What I have to do is loops through these numbers and find whether the numbers are increasing or decreasing for 1-number intervals, 2- number intervals, 3-number intervals, and 4-number intervals. Then I have to print what percentage is increasing and what percentage is decreasing (if it's neither increasing nor decreasing then it will not be counted into the percentages). For example, say the numbers inputted are 1,2,3,2,4; The code is supposed to output "For 1 day intervals: 75% were increasing and 25% were decreasing". This needs to be repeated up til 4-day intervals

Comment: you've listed several requirements. take them one step at a time. do you know how to iterate through the `lista` contents and determine if the numbers are increasing or decreasing?

Comment: do you know how to compare only 2 numbers for greater than/less than?

Comment: Thank you for responding! I do know how to loop through lists but I don't know how to determine whether the contents are increasing or decreasing. I assume the loop to loop through lista would look like this:
    i = 0
    size = len(lista) 
    while i < size :
        print(lista[i]) 
        i += 1

Comment: Yes, to compare 2 values it would just be: print(value1 > value2). If that's true then the statement would print True

Comment: So I had to google what the enumerate function does because I haven't learned it yet, and what I learned was that it is a counter for the list? Also, the code is giving a list index out of range error.

Comment: Ok! I'm sorry if I'm asking a lot, but how? I changed the statement to 
    for i in range(len(lista)
but how do I remove the index error?

Comment: I actually just went avoided using the enumerate function altogether, and instead changed the code to:

for i in range(len(lista)-1):
    if lista[i] < lista[i+1]:
        print('increasing')
    else:
        print('decreasing')

Comment: yes good, use what you are familiar with and makes sense to you. keep going and if you get stuck, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52797347/edit) and update your question and code